# Java Applet in Webbrowser control breaks stdin

Tags: java, winapi, applet, webbrowser-control, atl

I am using the IE WebBrowser Control in my application / process.  It is implemented with ATL running in a 32-bit application on Windows.

This process reads from stdin using GetStdHandle & ReadFile.

Whenever the WebBrowser control renders a page with a java applet (e.g. the applets on this page:  http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/Java/applets.htm), something in the Java engine is closing the stdin handle.

The result is that ReadFile returns FALSE, with GetLastError() returning ERROR_PIPE_BROKEN.

I tried using SetHandleInformation to prevent closing of the handle, and it supposedly succeeded, but the handle is still broken.

I need stdin to work as that is my communication channel with the calling process.

I did find a workaround for this problem, but wonder if there's a better solution.

**Workaround**

The workaround is to get the stdio handles at startup and then hide them from any other callers so the Java engine doesn't find and break them later.  Example:

```
// Sock the handles away
HANDLE hStdIn  = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE hStdErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

// Hide them from anyone else, especially Java
SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE,  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE,  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
```

Is there a better solution?  Or can anyone explain why Java applets are closing stdio handles and whether this can be avoided?

Comment: Have you checked the Java console to see if it's not just a SecurityManager problem? Did you sign your applet? We need more information and some code would help. How are you requesting permission to read from stdin (I assume you mean System.in).

Comment: I am not the author of the Java applet.  This appears to happen with _any_ Java applet.  The question is why does ANY Java Applet embedded in the IE WebBrowser control cause stdin to be broken in the process that is hosting the WebBrowser control.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question. Sorry. I thought this was a Java question but it's more of a Visual C++ question. Probably should remove the java tag.

Comment: No problem.  The java question is:  Why are _all_ java applets closing the stdio handles on Windows?  So I think the java applet tag is appropriate.  But I've found a workaround that I will add to the question.